# Changing span text with js

Tags: javascript, html

I am having this issue with changing the span text by javascript. I am trying to make an error message appears on submitting wrong input. How can I fix this?

```js
        function SubmitFunc() {
            var studentNameInput = document.getElementById("student-name");
            CheckInputLetters(studentNameInput);

        }
        function CheckInputLetters(input) {
            if (!/^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/.test(input.value)) {
                document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "error";
            }
        }
```

```html
    <label class="data-lbls data-titles-dec">FullName</label>
    <input class="input-style" type="text" id="student-name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" />
    <span id="name-error" style="float:right;"></span>
```

Comment: Code looks fine. problem must be related to the form submitting and refreshing the page, thus losing the text you're adding to said span. Or something else not included in the question.

Comment: i try to alert the value of the span after changing it. The alert shows the new value but in the page it doesn't change at all.

Comment: That doesn't disprove my theory.

Comment: I tried to change styling like padding. It doesn't show an the page. I don't know what could prevent showing the new results.

Comment: You do know what happens when a form submits, right?

Comment: I actually don't and I think this was the issue. the containing `form` tag! when I changed it to a `div` tag it works! but I don't know how to fix while keeping the `form` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was about the containing form tag and the submit input. As the submit input refreshes the page everything changed was reset again. I change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`. Now it works

Answer (score -1):

If the form is submitted, the page will reload and you won't see the changes (error message). You can use the return value of the function to prevent the form submission if there is any validation error:

```js
function SubmitFunc() {
  var studentNameInput = document.getElementById("student-name");
  return CheckInputLetters(studentNameInput);
}

function CheckInputLetters(input) {
  if (!/^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$/.test(input.value)) {
    document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "error";
    return false; // error
  }
  return true; // no error
}
```

```html
<form id="some" onsubmit="return SubmitFunc()">
  <label class="data-lbls data-titles-dec">FullName</label>
  <input class="input-style" type="text" id="student-name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" />
  <span id="name-error" style="float:right;"></span>
  <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to reference the method via something like onblur in the input field:

```js
        function SubmitFunc() {
            var studentNameInput = document.getElementById("student-name");
            CheckInputLetters(studentNameInput);
        }
        function CheckInputLetters(input) {
            if (!/^[a-zA-Z_\s]+$/.test(input.value)) {
                document.getElementById("name-error").innerHTML = "error";
            }
        }
```

```html
    <label class="data-lbls data-titles-dec">FullName</label>
    <input class="input-style" onblur="SubmitFunc();" type="text" id="student-name" placeholder="Enter Full Name" />
    <span id="name-error" style="float:right;"></span>
```

Comment: I'm glad I got downvoted for something that actually works: http://soulglo.com/what/44595682.html